# Кодировка данных из базы

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, yii, кодировка

Здравствуйте.
Есть старая база, менять в которой ничего нельзя. Мне нужно получать некоторые данные из базы. Проект на YII 1.1 . Подключаюсь:

```
    'db' => array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME,
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'enableProfiling' => true,
        'username' => DB_USER,
        'password' => DB_PASS,
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
```

Проверка через запросы:

```
SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA S
WHERE schema_name = "schemaname";
SELECT CCSA.character_set_name FROM information_schema.`TABLES` T,
       information_schema.`COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY` CCSA
WHERE CCSA.collation_name = T.table_collation
  AND T.table_schema = "schemaname"
  AND T.table_name = "tablename";
```

выводит для базы `cp1251`, для нужной таблицы - `binary`. Я хотел бы получать данные в кодировке utf-8, т.к. все файлы отображений и js сохранены в ней. Сейчас или приходится прописывать в html и в php заголоки utf-8, тогда данные из таблицы отображаются иероглифами, или ставить windows-1251, удалять `charset` из конфига YII БД, тогда иероглифами отображается кириллица прописанная в html-файлах.
Как можно получать данные в utf-8, чтобы избежать этой путанницы?

Comment: я сам немного в этом всем до сих пор путаюсь (точнее, в правилах, по которым работает mysql), но: вы не пробовали ставить `'charset' => 'cp1251'`?

Comment: @Etki, пробовал. Самое интересное, что тогда вопросительные знаки отображаются вместо данных из базы. А вывод кодировки данных выдает ASCII.

Comment: боюсь, тут дело в [типе данных](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html). В этом случае вы не можете обеспечить автоматическую конвертацию кодировки на стороне базы обычным SET NAMES, но, возможно, есть какие-нибудь хаки типа "использовать binary как cp1251", я бы копал в эту сторону.

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что можно добиться адекватного поведения от фреймворка, если в базе данных мешанина и "бинарные" строки.

Можете попробовать применить преобразования в `CActiveRecord::afterFind`, например. Если в строку попадают неиспорченные данные, просто в неверной кодировке, то после заполнения активной записи можно пройтись по строковым полям и перекодировать значения.

Если значения нужно ещё и записывать, то меняйте кодировку назад в `CActiveRecord::beforeValidate`.

Если таких записей и полей много, то задача вполне решаема в общем виде с помощью поведений.